# Getting an odd result: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I keep getting weird results from this query.

Not that I am not using PDA because this is just a prototype. In production I plan on tightening all of the screws and making it more secure.

```
include ('../includes/DBConnect.php'); //exactly how it is in other working files
$query = "SELECT * FROM CHARACTERS WHERE USER_ID=(SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL='"+$_SESSION['user']+"') ORDER BY id DESC"; //I have copy pasted this into mysql and it worked, switching the session variable with a string
```

I get an error with the this line

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($character_list)){

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Node2\public\main.php on line 36
```

I know this has to be stupid. I can't figure it out. I just looked at documentation and other files I have written that worked. And a few stack overflow threads to no avail.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Some advice.  ***Never*** assume an SQL query succeeded!  ***Always*** check to be sure it did.  Add in some error checking.  `if($character_list === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($conn); }`

Comment: Ty! will do, Rocket :D

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `+` instead of `.` to concatenate strings.  Gotta remember this is PHP, not JavaScript ;)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM CHARACTERS WHERE USER_ID=(SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL='".$_SESSION['user']."') ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

THank you so much! Why does php even do that! aaaahhhh ;(